# Which applications offering search functions opens when pressing Ctrl+Space?

Tags: software-recommendation, mate, ubuntu-mate

After installing a bunch of packages from the MATE desktop, the following application pops up when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> which I'm very used to use for something else (auto-completion in NetBeans).

I'm using Ubuntu 16.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application is called `synapse`. One can open a configuration dialog pressing the round symbol in the upper right corner and deactive the start or change the shortkey for displaying.